# What is the standard way of having constant content (headers, footers, sidebars) across a website?

Tags: css, html

I've just started web programming, but I can't find anything about how to define an html element (the best example is probably a header, like the one at the top of stackoverflow) in one file, and use it in every part of your website.

I've read something about frames, but they're deprecated; using JQuery to dynamically load content, but that would look shabby as JQuery only runs after the rest of the document has loaded; and some sites even seem to have their headers actually written out on each page, which seems like a waste of time.

What should I be doing in this case?

Comment: Just have one page for the web site?!

Comment: But what would I do about the different pages of content I want?

Comment: Has sarcasm not reached your parts?

Comment: Look into Templates. Expression Web uses .dwt files -- "Dynamic Web Template" files, and if I recall correctly, you can apply these template to any new page you create, and on these new pages, it's designed to not let you edit any of the html marked as template. (I only know very basic web development stuff, or I'd give you a better answer sorry.) [Web Templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php `include` may help you (link below)

[PHP Include Files](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)

Your code would look something like this:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have the server generate the response page on the fly and append the headers at response time using something like JSP or PHP.  You can still use frames if you really want.  You can also use JavaScript to pull in content on the page as well.  However, this is not exactly good practice because if the user has JavaScript disabled, they will see no header.  The server side appending is more accepted because it doesn't depend on what the client has enabled.

Comment: Can you link me a guide on how to do something like that?

Comment: @Miguel - pick a CMS Joomla, Drupal, Wordpress, ... Your chalice - Your poison.

Comment: Well I had a look at Wordpress, but it seems like you no longer have access to the html files themselves, and it's quite restrictive. Is there no way to do without losing total control over your content?

Comment: Just search for tutorials on JSP or PHP.  They are fundamental lessons taught in any tutorial for each language.  You *will* need some sort of server software to do this though whether that be through localhost or a remote site.  I found this just by googling: http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/11/servlet-jsps-create-easy-dynamic-web.html I highly recommend `Netbeans` as an IDE to learn on because it makes turnaround time in development very quick.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done on the server either with [Server Side Includes in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html) (not requiring use of any server side language) or with the server side programming language of your choice - usually either using the concepts of page templates, sections, partials or includes (or a combination thereof).

PHP has the [Include function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), which has already been mentioned, ASP.NET web forms have [Master Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages) and [User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and ASP.NET MVC has [layouts](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-page-layouts-with-view-master-pages-cs) and [partials](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-4). I imagine Ruby on Rails, Java Server Pages and any other server side frameworks will have similar constructs for common layout templates and shared content between pages.

The point is that there are at least as many methods of constructing pages with shared or common elements as there are frameworks for building pages - but no method involves "just" HTML.

Find the right one for you.